# c++ (My code is stuck in the first function)

Tags: c++, function

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct student_type{
    char name[50];
    int score;
    float grade;
}studs[1];

void getData(student_type studs[]){
    int label=1;
    for(student_type *p=studs; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
        cout<<"Student " << label++;
        cout<<"\nName: ";
        cin.get(p->name,50);
        cout<<"Test Score: ";
        cin >> p->score;
        cin.get();
    }
}

void determineGrade(student_type studs[]){
    for(student_type *p; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
        if(p->score<=69&&p->score>=0){
            p->grade=5.00;
        } else if(p->score<=73&&p->score>=70){
            p->grade=3.00;
        } else if(p->score<=77&&p->score>=74){
            p->grade=2.75;
        } else if(p->score<=80&&p->score>=78){
            p->grade=2.50;
        } else if(p->score<=83&&p->score>=81){
            p->grade=2.25;
        } else if(p->score<=87&&p->score>=84){
            p->grade=2.00;
        } else if(p->score<=90&&p->score>=88){
            p->grade=1.75;
        } else if(p->score<=93&&p->score>=91){
            p->grade=1.50;
        } else if(p->score<=97&&p->score>=94){
            p->grade=1.25;
        } else {
            p->grade=1.00;
        }
    }
}

void printData(student_type studs[]){
    int label=1;
    for(student_type *p=studs; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
        cout<<"Student " << label++;
        cout<< "\n Name: "<<p->name;
        cout<< "\n Test Score: "<<p->score;
        cout<< "\n Grade: "<<p->grade << endl << endl;
    }
}

int returnGrade(student_type studs[]){
    int box=0;
    box=studs[0].score;

    for(student_type *p=studs; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
        if(p->score>box){
            box=0;
            box=p->score;
        }
    }return box;
}

void highestScorers(student_type studs[], int box){
    cout<< "\n\nHIGHEST SCORERS:" << endl; 
    for(student_type *p; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
        if(box==p->score){
            cout<< p->name << endl;
        }
    }
}

main(){
    getData(studs);
    determineGrade(studs);
    printData(studs);
    int box=returnGrade(studs);
    highestScorers(studs, box);
}
```

I don't know why my code is stuck in the getData part, I also did that in another pc but there after the first loop in getData the compiler shows "Does not work. Months ago I already did that and it worked and it is when I'm just starting with structs and pointer arithmetic, I checked my old code, my old code and my new code(the code i post) is exactly the same but its just that this code are having issues while my old code doesn't.

Since it is the getData function that is has some problems, this is my old code that worked. You'll see here that it is similar but my new code doesn't work.

```
void getData(student_type studs[]){
    int label=1;
for(student_type *p=studs; p<=&studs[1]; ++p) {
    cout<< "Student " << label ;
    cout<< "\nName: ";
    cin.get(p->name, 50);
    do {
        cout<< "Score: ";
        cin >> p->score;
    } while (p->score>100 || p->score<0);
    cout<< endl;
    ++label;
        cin.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"the compiler shows "Does not work"* I highly doubt it. If the compiler (or anything, actually) is really throwing an error, please post the exact text of the error.

Comment: Read `for(student_type *p; p<=&studs[1]; ++p)` very carefully.  What does `p` point to?  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: `main()` function should be `int main(void)` and should return an `int`

Comment: `student_type *p;` Where is `p` initialisation?

Comment: Are these loops defined behavior? I am confused at this `c` code especially because studs has 1 element??

Comment: @NathanOliver for(student_type *p=studs; p<=&studs[1]; ++p) just a typo lol sorry. Nonetheless it is still stuck at the getData function

Comment: `p<=&studs[1]` is also not correct.  `studs[1]` does not exist.  Should be `p<&studs[1]`

Comment: determineGrade() also has the initialization bug.

Comment: well it is not "just a typo", it is undefined behaivour and thus it is pointless to look for any other problems in this code, before you fix this. Do you really get same behaviour after fixing this? Maybe it would even be better to close this one and open a new question, as you already got answers adressing exactly that issue. In general it is not nice to fix code in your question after you got answers

Comment: @NathanOliver that was a big part of my confusion.

Comment: If these are really typos please update your post with what you really have.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the loop if you only have 1 element even if the condition is fixed.

Comment: @drescherjm it really is 5, I just changed it to 1 so I can easily check if the code works or not.

Comment: Fix  `for (student_type *p;`  in the  `determineGrade`. and `highestScorers`

Comment: You still have `studs[1]` in many places.

Comment: Aslo, condition should be `p<&studs[1]`

Comment: Please don't add anything like "QUESTION SOLVED" to questions. If this question is useful to anyone in the future, it's just spam. If it's not useful it will probably get deleted at some point. I recommend you to take the [tour] around the site and see [ask] to write better questions in the future :)

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use the standard library. Most of the complexity would be gone with modern `c++`. I mean by using `std::vector<student_type>` instead of studs the program would be less error prone.

Comment: as you accepted the answer adressing the issue in your original post, you should reroll the fix in your question. Currently this q&a makes no sense, because the accepted answer is talking about an issue that is not present in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the following line

```
    for(student_type *p; p<=&studs[1]; ++p){
```

You should initialize the variable `p` is not initialized. You should set it to a known value. I guess you'd want to initialize it as follows. Also your stop condition goes one too far: use `<` instead of `<=`.

```
    for(student_type *p=studs; p<&studs[1]; ++p){
```

Comment: Yep I know, that's just a typo. Nonetheless it is still stuck

Comment: Your suggested code is still bugged.  Look at the condition.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. Fixed the condition.